# getting data in specified format for flot bar charts

Tags: javascript, php, flot

I am trying ti plot a flot bar chart and I am unable to fetch the data in the way which flot requires.please correct me where I am doing mistake? My query returns results like
A-250,B-100,C-300 etc.
My code is shown below :

```
<?php 
require_once('../../Connections/finalkms.php'); 

mysql_select_db($database_finalkms, $finalkms);
$query_getmaincatdetails = "SELECT `EquipmentMainCatagory`,count(`EquipmentMainCatagory`) FROM `assetinfo` group by EquipmentMainCatagory HAVING EquipmentMainCatagory !=''";
$getmaincatdetails = mysql_query($query_getmaincatdetails, $finalkms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getmaincatdetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmaincatdetails);
$totalRows_getmaincatdetails = mysql_num_rows($getmaincatdetails);

         for ($i = 1; $i <=$totalRows_getmaincatdetails ; $i++) 
         { 

          $ticks[] = array( $i,(int)$row_getmaincatdetails['EquipmentMainCatagory']);

          $data[] = array( $i,(int)$row_getmaincatdetails['count(`EquipmentMainCatagory`)']);           

          }

    $jsonTable = json_encode(array("data" => $data, "ticks" => $ticks));

?>
```

In Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var data1 =<?php echo $jsonTable;?>;

        var options = {
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true
                }
            }         
        };

$(document).ready(function () {
            $.plot($("#placeholder"),options);

        });


</script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: How do you want the chat to be displayed? What does A-250 means for you? What is A and what is 250?

Comment: @user3058736 This should guide you :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862617/create-flot-on-php-data

Comment: What do you want  to display the ticks or data?

Answer (score 2):

PHP looks ok, on the JS side, you need something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var dataAndTicks = <?php echo $jsonTable;?>;

    var options = {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: dataAndTicks['ticks']
        }
    };

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $.plot($("#placeholder"),dataAndTicks['data'], options);

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For flot charts the syntax is as follows:

```
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, options)
```

Example

```
var options = {
    series: {
        lines: { show: true },
        points: { show: true }
    }
};

    var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

    $.plot("#placeholder", [ d2 ], $options);
```

Comment: Hi Nouphal.M I have done that also still the data when I am alerting its showing me as [Object,Object]. I am not gettingg the data.please help.

Comment: The data1 is a json object while plot data must be an array